# Join twitter bootstrap search box and Search button and curve the right side of Search button

Tags: html, css, search, button, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bootstrap code

```
 <div class="input-append" align="center" > 
           <input type="text" name="q" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Snipp or Tag"/> 

           <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 

        </div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRK9y/)

Is  there a way to join the Search box and Search button and also curve the right hand side of `Search` button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css class that controls the `border-radius` of the Search button is `.form-search .input-append .btn`. To apply that class, add a form or div surrounding the `input-append` div with that class.

Like this:

```
<div class="form-search">
 <div class="input-append"> 
  <input type="text" name="q" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Snipp or Tag"/><button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), and here's an update to your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRK9y/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this.

```
input.search-query {
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;

    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```